# Using options in Apache Commons CLI without hyphen

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons

Is there a proper way of handling options using Apache Commons CLI without a hyphen? So instead of entering "-help" a normal "help" should also work? Or is this not possible/intended because an option would be no longer distinguishable from an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is this not possible/intended because an option would be no longer distinguishable from an argument?

Absolutely, that's the reason. And all the libraries I know use the hyphen.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly correct. It uses a mix, the second param is an _action_ and then, you can have options, eg: `git commit -a -m "hello"` and `git commit -m "hello" -a`

Comment: It may be called an 'action,' but I think the point is that this a feature unfortunately not supported by Apache Commons CLI.